# symfony2 doctrine query builder collection comparaison

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have theses entities :

- User
- Job
- Language

a User can speak one or many languages

a Job can require one or Many languages

i would like to filter, for a specific Job, all the users having all the required languages for this job.

Example :

- User1 speaks English + French
- User2 speaks English + Spanish
- Job1 requires English
- Job2 requires English + Spanish

then :

- User1 & User2 should match for Job1
- User2 only matches for Job2

here is my query builder:

```
public function getMatchingUsersFromJob($job) {
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('j')
        ->from('MyBundle:User', 'u')
        ->join('u.languages', 'l')
    ;
    if( $job->getLanguages()->count() > 0 ){
        $i = 1;
        foreach( $job->getLanguages() as $language) {
            $qb->andWhere('l.name = :language'.$i)
                ->setParameter('language'.$i, $language->getName() )
            ;
            $i++;
        }
    }
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Problem is : i always get an empty result...

How can i compare arraycollections ? and be sure to select all User having all the required languages ?

Answer (score 2):

You're using `$qb->andWhere('l.name = :language'.$i)`.
It means you want the `l.name` must be iqual to many `$language->getName()` that your `$job` has.
You could transform the id's in a string to use `$qb->Where('l.name IN :languages')`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a left join.

Job's required languages left join user spoken languages. If any row has a null joined, then your user is not eligible for the job. If all rows has a match, then your user is eligible for the job.